# How can I add markers to a map from a different activity in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

So, I have an Activity with a Fragment that stores input latitude and longitude, and another Activity with a Fragment containing a map. How can I store and transfer the latitude and longitude from one Activity to another? I have an inkling this would need an SQLite database, but I'm unfamiliar with that. Can someone please provide a suggestion/example of how I'd do that? I know how to create markers and write to files but that would be cumbersome and take up unnecessary memory.

Comment: use `Intent` to send and receive data between `Activities` and further reading [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) here.

Comment: but that wouldn't store any data. @Spurdow

Comment: use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if you arent comfortable with sqlite yet.